# Create a model formula programmatically

Tags: julia

Is there a way to create a StatsModels formula programmatically? For example, suppose I want to create a formula like `@formula(y ~ x1 + x2)` for any number of predictor terms. In other words, I'd like to create a function that behaves as follows:

```
julia> using StatsModels

julia> make_formula(3)
FormulaTerm
Response:
  y(unknown)
Predictors:
  x1(unknown)
  x2(unknown)
  x3(unknown)

julia> make_formula(3) == @formula(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3)
true
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

As of StatsModels version 0.6.x, you can create formula terms using term constructors such as `Term` and `ConstantTerm`, or using the generic function `term`, which works on both numbers and symbols. The terms can then be combined using formula operators such as `+`, `&`, and `~`.

Here is how a simple formula can be constructed using `Term` constructors:

```
julia> f = Term(:y) ~ ConstantTerm(1) + Term(:x)
FormulaTerm
Response:
  y(unknown)
Predictors:
  1
  x(unknown)

julia> f == @formula(y ~ 1 + x)
true
```

And here is how you could use the `term` function to programmatically create a formula:

```
julia> function make_formula(n)
           term(:y) ~ sum(term.(Symbol.(string.("x", 1:n))))
       end
make_formula (generic function with 1 method)

julia> make_formula(3)
FormulaTerm
Response:
  y(unknown)
Predictors:
  x1(unknown)
  x2(unknown)
  x3(unknown)

julia> make_formula(3) == @formula(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3)
true
```

For more details, see the StatsModels documentation [here](https://juliastats.github.io/StatsModels.jl/stable/formula/#Constructing-a-formula-programatically-1).